# Best way for horizontal scrolling of image

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, horizontal-scrolling

what is the best way for horizontal scrolling of image in iphone sdk. Image has to be get from  web server something like lazy loading?

please help me.

Comment: Hello @Sathish if you have find any solution regarding your question than please share you solution here because it may help to other also,    and I also Need it so Please share!! Please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

First, set fixed size for your UIScrollView.

```
scroll.size = ... // your size
```

Next, determine width and height for contentSize of your scroll. Fix the height. the width is the value changeable. After each lazy image is loaded successfully, adjust the width.

Assume, all the image have the same height. Then, each time when there's an image is loaded, the code is:

(in the below code, I assume that the new image is appended. In your case, you can configure properly for your need)

```
float oldScrollWith = scroll.contentSize.width
// creat new_image_view (UIImageView)
// configure it to display in the scroll
...                       
new_image_view.frame = CGRectMake(oldScrollWidth, 0, imageViewWidth, fixed_image_height)

// append the new view to the scroll
float newScrollWidth = oldScrollWidth + new_image_view.frame.size.width // re-calculate the width for the contentSize of scroll
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(newScrollWidth, fixed_image_height);
[scroll addSubview:new_image_view];
```